# Differences declaring Ruby variables based on name case

Tags: ruby, variables

I think (and hope) to know differences declaring variables in the following ways:

```
# This declares a local variable
variable_name

# This declares a global variable (editable from the client side)
VARIABLE_NAME
```

but what about this:

```
VARIABLE_name
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a constant. All constants in ruby start with capital letter.

Starting with:

- $ global variable
- [A-Z] constant
- @@ class variable
- @ instance variable
- [a-z] or _ local variable, also block variable

I have no idea what "editable from client side" mans, but constants should not be changed once set. Ruby, in this version will allow it (with warning), but some next version might as well disallow it.